# Where does one connect with government departments world-over to suggest world-changing ideas?

Tags: infrastructure

I am aware that you can mail departments through the Whitehouse site. I am concerned with posing philanthropic ideas to political bodies.

What is the best way to reach the relevant people that can make great politics-related innovative thinking possible?

Comment: Bilderberger group type ideas?  Or something that will take the established elite out of power?  If the latter I recommend going to a nearby despot and requesting to be arrested and held as a political prisoner.  That will save your some heartache and effort and just get you to the end you are heading towards.

Comment: What makes you think the most relevant people are in **government**? Did Martin Luther King, Gandhi, Thomas Jefferson, Stalin, or Mao contact government to make their inovative political ideas possible? Individuals outside of government are far more effective.

Comment: The world needs more than changes in attitude. These are initiatives that can functionally tackle real-world problems. I can't elaborate on what those initiatives would be as they really could apply to any department. I'm from South Africa btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to connect with specific government departments of all nations other than by contacting each one individually. If your idea is truly relevant to many nations then you might try an appropriate United Nations body.

Comment: @WarrenvanRooyen - Good luck.  I'm definitely curious what your ideas are, now.

Comment: This was the particular one:

At high-accident intersections, boxes can be installed 20-40 metres away from the intersection on either side.

They would detect a speed that would be considered too fast to stop at a red light. A box beneath the robot facing the intersecting traffic would flash rapidly indicating that they need to come to a halt urgently because an oncoming vehicle is not going to stop even though it's a green light for them.

This will eliminate accidents in the case of skipping red lights, failed brakes etc.

Comment: Take this to a company that makes traffic signals. And it's nothing to do with politics.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Definitely the best way to handle this specific idea, but the *question* was on target.